# How to make my Webparts settings visible to other people?

Tags: asp.net, web-parts

I want to build a web site that gives every user a home page. The user can customize the layout of his/her own home page using webparts functionality. Now I wish to have visitors to one's homepage see that webparts that the owner chooses to show, how can I achieve this? Thanks for reading this question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ASP.NET 2.0 starter kit called "The Beer House" that may help you. You can find it here: http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/the-beer-house.

If I remember correctly, the homepage can be customised to use web parts. Its been a while since I last looked at this project but it may prove useful as starter in how to make a customised page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know how to customize a portal I just don't know how to enable other people to view my customized page. By default you can only see your own personalization settings.